# Place Marker on center of polyline

Tags: google-maps-api-3

i am using Google's direction service alongside the Polyline class to draw lines along a road with custom colors. I want to be able to place a market on the center of a polyline. I have tried using the following code:

```
function Marker(start, end) {
    var midP = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(start, end, 0.5);
    // console.log(map);
    // console.log(midP);
    var options = {
        position: midP
    };
    marker = new google.maps.Marker(options);
    marker.setMap(map);
}
```

start and end are the start and end points of a given polyline.

However the marker doesn't fall on the polyline. It appears to untill you zoom in.
I would appreciate any help on how to get this right. Thanks

Comment: If you are looking for a marker along a route: [example of marker every 2km along a route](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polyline_example_kmmarkers_0.html), [example of markers at 9.5km and 64.8km along a route](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_kmmarkersC.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the *midpoint* of the polyline, i.e. the point at which you would have traveled have the distance following the route. Is that right?

Then I would use an algorithm like [this one which finds the midpoint of a polyline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542835/polyline-label-positioning-algorithm). The code in that answer is written for a polyline "defined as a series of [x,y] points", but could easily be adapted to use a Maps API polyline.